# python subprocess missing arguments

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-arguments

Have been trying to get something like this to work for a while, the below doesn't seem to be sending the correct arg to the c program arg_count, which outputs `argc = 1`. When I'm pretty sure I would like it to be `2`. `./arg_count -arg` from the shell outputs 2...

I have tried with another arg (so it would output 3 in the shell) and it still outputs 1 when calling via subprocess.

```
import subprocess
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["./args/Release/arg_count", "-arg"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = pipe.communicate()
result = out.decode()
print "Result : ",result
print "Error : ",err
```

Any idea where im falling over? I'm running linux btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html):

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use
>   the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is
>   recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

Thus,

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen("./args/Release/arg_count -arg", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to fix the argument issue, but now I get no output whatsoever...

Comment: for whatever reason, the script has to be in the same directory as the executable to get a valid result? or i dont know how to write a filepath...

Comment: That shouldn't have to be the case; I can easily put my version of `arg_count` (in this case a 2-line Python script) in a different directory and get the correct result. Unless your `arg_count` itself has some awkward problem.

Comment: Wasn't getting errors with arguments with out options used as a sequence, but when options paired with args (-arg option) the targeted process couldn't assign the option to the corresponding arguments (in my case 'Missing argument for option x')
Used your solution and passed args as a string fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

If `shell=True` then your call is equivalent to:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', "./args/Release/arg_count", "-arg"],
             stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

i.e., `-arg` is passed to the shell itself and not your program. Drop `shell=True` to pass `-arg` to the program:

```
proc = Popen(["./args/Release/arg_count", "-arg"],
             stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

If you don't need to capture `stderr` separately from `stdout` then you could use `check_output()`:

```
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT

output = check_output(["./args/Release/arg_count", "-arg"]) # or
output_and_errors = check_output(["./args/Release/arg_count", "-arg"],
                                 stderr=STDOUT)
```